# "Обрезаные" данные получаемые с http запросом на андроид.

Tags: c#, android, http

Делаю запрос с андроида на сервер и возвращаю то что выдает скрипт. Но почему-то возврощается не весь контент. Кто виноват?

```
public String dataL()
        {
            String strURL = "http://madoffice.net/calc/index.php";
            HttpWebRequest req;
            HttpWebResponse resp;
            StreamReader sr;
            string content;

            req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURL);
            resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
            content = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            return content;
        }

send.Click += delegate
        {
            value = title.Text;

               PostMethod("value=" + value + " " + result.ToString(), "http://madoffice.net/calc/sluz.php");
              dataRequest = dataL();              
              data.Text = string.Format("{0}",dataRequest); 
        };
```

Comment: Как мне кажется вся причина в том, что Вы получаете ответ в UI потоке, а на Андроиде время загруженности UI потока ограниченно, поэтому Вы получаете только ту часть которая успевает загрузиться!

Comment: Я как-то не наблюдаю тут признаков выполнения этого кода во вторичном потоке...    
Я надеюсь, это все происходит не в UI-потоке?

Comment: Метод dataL() абсолютно синхронный и если вызывается из ЮИ потока, то в нем и выполняется. К тому же в нем не все очищается.